# vSphere errors when replacing certificate

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

When I try replacing my machine certificate with one I just got from ZeroSSL, I get the following error:

```
Invalid base64 encoded X509 certificate string
```

If I remove the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and such and all whitespace, it gives me

```
String index out of range: -1
```

I tried out the certificate on a quick nginx instance and it works fine. What can I do?

I saw articles online about carefully manipulating the ca bundle but I can't do that, zerossl just gives me the three files already compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be missing fields in the certificate like organization, country, etc. Generating a CSR from vCenter fixed the issue.